# discord.js bot performance monitoring

Tags: javascript, node.js, networking, discord.js, performance-testing

I have created a Discord bot using discord.js, and I want to monitor the overall performance of the bot such as response time, latency, throughput, etc.

As of right now, I only have back-end development, which is the Discord bot. I deployed the bot on Heroku, and I tried the New Relic APM, but it showing no results. Is there any third-party apps that I can use to monitor the performance of the Discord bot? Or is web development for the bot is required for monitoring?